# Which htaccess rules would allow for navigating a webapp as specified?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a Web App stored in a directory `htdocs/webapp`.
The PHP code is in an extra subdirectory on its own: `htdocs/webapp/php` which is where the entry point for my web app (`index.php`) is.

The `.htaccess` inside `htdocs/webapp/php` has the following content, especially the `RewriteRule`s:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/php

# page
RewriteRule    ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$  index.php?page=$1&subpage=home [QSA]
# page+subpage
RewriteRule    ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$  index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2 [QSA]
```

Now, my `index.php` contain links and stuff.
I would like to write links so that, e.g. going to the `login` page would read in the HTML something like:

```html
<base href="php/"/>
...
<a href="login">Login</a>
```

With my current setup, I get the above link to point to `webapp/php/php/login` instead of `webapp/php/login`.

How could I fix this using a `.htaccess` directive? I suspect it has to do with the `RewriteBase` rule, but omitting it produces the same behavior and providing the absolute path:

```
RewriteBase /C:/Bitnami/wampstack-7.4.13-0/apache2/htdocs/webapp/php
```

will trigger a 403 error.

Note that I need

```html
<base href="php/"/>
```

because otherwise trying following different page will cause the links to "accumulate" pages, e.g.

```html
<a href="page2">Login</a>
```

will go to `webapp/php/page1/page2` if the link is followed from `page1`, but I would like to get to `webapp/php/page2`.

Comment: Try changing `<base href="php/">` to `<base href="/webapp/php/">` Absoulte path in base tag should solve your problem.

Comment: @AmitVerma Thanks, it works! I knew I was missing something silly.